# Access Database engine Issue

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, 64-bit, microsoft-office, .net-framework

I have recently moved from *32 bit* to *64 bit* version PC which runs 32 bit version of Office package.

I have an application (`.net 4.0`) which handle excel files and which uses the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0.` (I did install [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255) in order to do this.)
But since I moved to 64 bit version this file handler comes up with below error.
[image]

Then I found this is because the 32 bit version of Access Database Engine, so that I tried installing 64 bit version of Access Database Engine which doesn’t allow me since I have 32 bit version of office product.

[image]

Is there any work around this apart from using 64 bit Office Product?

Comment: compile the .Net app as x86 instead of AnyCPU.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Great it worked. Please add as an answer! Also found something related [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b5a79958-5bce-4229-a69f-75589b6240a8/faq-item-solution-fails-on-64-bit-system-with-error-microsoftjetoledb40-provider-is-not?forum=adodotnetdataproviders)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty done. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compile the application as AnyCPU, the program will run as 32Bit on a 32Bit and as 64Bit on a 64Bit Windows. And when you only have the 32Bit Engine installed you get an error. Also side by side installation of the 32Bit and 64Bit Engine is not supported.

The solution is to explicitly compile the application as x86 (32Bit). Now it runs all the time as a 32Bit application and uses the 32Bit engine.